# Sorting of list buffer scala

Tags: scala

I have a `ListBuffer` of `Map`s in scala. All maps inside the buffer contain some keys. For example:

```
ListBuffer(
  Map(
    "date" -> 24092018,
    "datetime" -> "24-09-2018 11:23:44",
    "lat" -> "48.33"
  ),Map(
    "date" -> 24092018,
    "datetime" -> "24-09-2018 11:53:44",
    "lat" -> "48.33"
  ),Map(
    "date" -> 23092018,
    "datetime" -> "23-09-2018 10:53:44",
    "lat" -> "48.33"
  )
)
```

I want to sort this `ListBuffer` based on `datetime` so that latest one will come first.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Show us some failed code so we can see what's going off track.

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy` is a method of the object (and reverse too); Directly from the language reference:

`def sortBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): ListBuffer[A]`

Sorts this `Seq` according to the Ordering which results from transforming an implicitly given Ordering with a transformation function.